# SCSS / CSS closest parent selector

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working with a codebase with multiple styles (coming from a redesign). I would like to be able to declare class="v1" or class="v2" on elements, to determine which style to use.

Importantly, some pages may contain elements with both styles, in which case the style applied should be whatever versioned parent is closest.  For instance, if the body is v1, but the div is v2, then any styles inside that should be v2.

In SCSS, I can do something like this:

```
.v1 {
  p {
    // stuff for version 1 of the styles
  }
}

.v2 {
  p {
    // stuff for version 2 of the css
  }
}
```

Which sort of gets me there, but v2 will always overwrite v1 because it is lower in the CSS.

For instance, the following should be red, then blue, then red, then blue. However, it is red, then blue, then blue, then blue.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .v1 span {
      color: red;
    }
    .v2 span {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body class="v1">
    <span>Outside</span>
    <div class="v2">
      <span>Div 1</span>
      <div class="v1">
        <span>Div 2</span>
        <div class="v2">
          <span>Div 3</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

### **Edit**

**Per the OP's comment, this answer only addresses the OP's specific test case, and does not fully resolve the issue.**

Have a look at [CSS Child Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

What you had before was telling the page to take everything inside the v1 class that was a span and apply the red color to it.  The spans inside the child divs were all inside the parent div that had a class of v1.  Using the child selector, you are specifically telling it to look for a child element of a span inside a specific class.

The following seems to work:

```
.v1 > span {
  color: red;
}
.v2 > span {
  color: blue;
}
```

You can check this example working here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/gerq2jbq/)

Comment: I wasnt sure if this would continue to work in deeper nesting but it does. http://jsfiddle.net/gerq2jbq/1/

Comment: That only works for this specific example (with spans right inside .v1 and .v2). The question was more general: suppose I have two stylesheets, for a nontrivial website, and I want them to apply but only in two different contexts. I have all the power of SCSS at my disposal.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that it does not fulfill all of the requirements.  I will edit again when I am able to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest CSS variables/custom properties here, like

```css
.v1 {
  --color: red;
}

.v2 {
  --color: blue;
}

span {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="v1">
  <span>Outside</span>
  <div class="v2">
    <span>Div 1</span>
    <div class="v1">
      <span>Div 2</span>
      <div class="v2">
        <span>Div 3</span>
        <div class="v1">
          <span>Div 4</span>
          <div class="v2">
            <span>Div 5</span>
            <div class="v1">
              <span>Div 6</span>
              <div class="v2">
                <p>
                  <span>Div 7</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```